# How to stop Hazelcast from automatic console print?

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using `Hazelcast` as a library in my program.

I don't want Hazelcast to print all the stuff to console while adding a node or creating `newHazelcastInstance`.

It should just add node in background without printing? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your logging framework you are using, or how you have configured Hazelcast.

For example if you are using log4j and have selected the log4j logger in Hazelcast, then you could filter out the Hazelcast log entries.

Comment: yes got it. Changing it through system prperty does the trick.